# String.Remove giving error

Tags: c#

I am passing different file names to the below code sample and getting error as below. But for the same data it is working fine at my end but giving these errors in client end.

Please suggest me if it can occur because of some other reason. Note: This is a maintenance code, written by someone else, I need to fix the issue and if possible improve it.

File name sample:

```
222233334444555561_l.jpg
222233334444555561_l1.jpg
```

Code:

```
if (sFileName.LastIndexOf('_') != -1)
{
    if (fileName.IndexOf("l1") != -1)
        sVin = sFileName.Remove(sFileName.LastIndexOf('_'), 7);
    else
        sVin = sFileName.Remove(sFileName.LastIndexOf('_'), 6);
}
```

Error at line:

```
sVin = sFileName.Remove(sFileName.LastIndexOf('_'), 7);
```

Which means error coming for input samples like: `222233334444555561_l1.jpg`

Error Message:

```
ERROR MESSAGE : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and count must refer to a location   within the string.

Parameter name: count
  at System.String.Remove(Int32 startIndex, Int32 count)
```

Comment: Could the user's filename have `l1` in it somewhere before the underscore?

Comment: sVin = sFileName.Remove(sFileName.LastIndexOf('_'), 7);

LastIndexOf will not be able to find "_" from index 7, so it wont return any string, hence Remove will fail.

Comment: Don't write code that you **know** can fail.

Comment: @HansPassant..Yes i agree..but where does it fail?

Comment: Can you rebuild the code? Are you seeing this exception in the IDE? I don't know how string can be surrounded between single quotes. Also, your code has this line `if (fileName.IndexOf("l1") != -1)` instead of `if (sFileName.IndexOf("l1") != -1)`.

Comment: No...when the app runs at client end..

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "222233334444555561_l1.jpg";
int underScorePos = s.LastIndexOf("_");
if (underScorePos != -1)
    s = s.Substring(1, underScorePos - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it to avoid ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception

```
        int lastIndex = sFileName.LastIndexOf('_');
        if (lastIndex != -1)
        {
            sVin = sFileName.Remove(lastIndex, sFileName.Length - lastIndex);
        }
```